# Abstracting Batch Process SFTP Multiple Destination & Automatic Retries

Tags: java, oracle, ftp, solaris, batch-processing

I do a lot of batch processing work using an in house Java framework. One of the activities that is particularly troublesome for us is SFTP where we run into two problems:

1. Sending files to multiple destinations, where if one destination is unavailable the entire process stops.
2. No automatic retries, where some network hiccup causes the batch process to stop.

Currently, we use Control-M for storing all of the SFTP related information:

1. Host & Path of From & To
2. PGP key information
3. Username & password

While it's certainly possible to do something with Control-M to solve these problems, I find it a cumbersome beast. I am looking for suggestions on a way of abstracting file transfer so that a batch process can generate a file, put it into some local folder, and decouple the transfer to the destination(s) in a robust fashion, whilst providing alerting/reporting when things go wrong without stopping.

In particular I am looking for anything that does this off the shelf as opposed to having to write such a tool myself.

**Environment**

- Solaris 10
- Java 6
- Oracle 11
- Control-M 7

Answer (score 0):

- [JScape SFTP](http://www.jscape.com/) is an enterprise-level commercial SFTP system.
- [Aspera](http://asperasoft.com/) is an enterprise file transfer system which is much faster than SFTP; good for large files.
- [Signiant](http://www.signiant.com/) is another enterprise file transfer and workflow system. It's similar in speed to Aspera.